# django test: fixtures not loading with selenium

Tags: django, selenium

My fixtures are correctly loaded by TestCase test:

like in:

```
class Test_test_fixture(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['lwt/fixtures/myfix.json']

    def setUp(self):
        super(Test_test_fixture, self).setUpClass()
        print(User.objects.all())
        ..
```

But doing the same thing with Selenium is printing an empty query:

```
class Selenium_fixtures(StaticLiveServerTestCase):  

    fixtures = ['lwt/fixtures/myfix.json']

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(Selenium_fixtures, self).setUpClass()
        print(User.objects.all())
        ...
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT** : I can use `setUp` (not `setUpClass`). It's working.

But `setUpClass`  with fixtures is not. it seems to overwrite the fixture with new blank data from the models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that your fixtures are loaded in `setUpClass` level, `setUpClass`  is used to perform class-wide initialization/configuration and called once for the TestCase before running any of the tests. Similarly tearDownClass is called after all the tests have run.

So using loaded data from fixtures will be possible only with `setUp`